# Div tag moved outside the form when JQuery populates the Div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jsp

So I have a form, and within a form there's a div tag that will be populated with another jsp page as part of a Jquery dialog popup when user clicks on a button within the form. However, once the popup shows up and I inspected the html element, the div section has been moved outside of the form and I have no idea why that is happening. The div is declared in the form but moved outside of it when the Jquery dialog popup window with the div section is populated. Anyone have an idea on why the div tag is behaving like that?

Here's the jsp portion:

```
<form:form ...> 
<div id="popUpDiv"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="openPopupWindow();"/> 
</form:form>
```

The Javascript portion:

```
function openPopupWindow(){ 
    var url = '/.../popUp.jsp';
    var ajaxParameter = {}; 
    createPopUp('popUpDiv', 'Title',url, ajaxParameter, 500, 350);
```

And the Jquery portion:

```
function createPopUp(divID, windowTitle,url, ajaxParameter, widths, heights){
var windowID = '#'+divID;

//delete the current open window if there is one.
jQuery(windowID).dialog('destroy');

jQuery(windowID).load(url, ajaxParameter);
jQuery(windowID).dialog({
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    //If this is enabled then the next time pop up page opens, it will resize every time a escape was pressed
    closeOnEscape: false,
    buttons:[
            { //Buttons for the form. (Submit the form and close)
                id: "Save",
                text: "Save",
                disabled: true,
                click: function() {
                    $("form").submit();
                    jQuery(windowID).html("");  //this workaround is necessary so the dialog opens subsequent times with the correct height
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
            },
            {
                id: "Cancel",
                text: "Cancel",
                click: function() {
                    jQuery(windowID).html("");  //this workaround is necessary so the dialog opens subsequent times with the correct height
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
             ]
    ,
    autoOpen: false,
    height: heights,
    width: widths,
    show: 'blind',
    position: 'center',
    title: 'Blah'
});

$('.ui-widget-overlay').live("click", function() {
    //Close the dialog
    jQuery(windowID).html(""); //this workaround is necessary so the dialog opens subsequent times with the correct height
    $(windowID).dialog("close");
 });

//open the window
jQuery(windowID).dialog('open');

}
```

This is what ends up happening using the browser viewer:

```
<form:form ...></form:form>
<div tabindex="-1" class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-popUpDiv" style="left: 530px; top: -665px; width: 500px; height: auto; display: block; z-index: 1002; outline-width: 0px; outline-style: none; outline-color: invert;" jQuery17108924731123454443="9">
<div class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" id="addCommentsPopUp" style="width: auto; height: 198px; min-height: 0px;" scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0" jQuery17108924731123454443="8"> </div></div>
```

I don't know why it's happening. Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: It is probably because the function you are using is appending the div back to the DOM in the parent of the form element instead of appending it back into the form element itself. That would be the most likely culprit. If you can change your code to appendTo() the form, it should solve your issue.